# Bootstrap row taking a extra column even when 12 column is already present

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am learning bootstrap grid. What I understand that a single row can contain maximum 12 column.

Here I have created a row under a medium *container*. The first elements spans till 11 column and the remaining spans single column. The row contains 12 column until the size of the viewport is medium. The moment size of screen becomes large, the row contains now 13 column. I am not able to understand why is it happening.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <title>pratice1 Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container-md text-center ">
        <div class="row text-white">
          <div class="col-11 bg-warning">1</div>
          <div class="col bg-danger">2</div>
          <div class="col bg-dark"> 3</div>
          <div class="col bg-info">4</div>
          <div class="col bg-primary">5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The `col` class is for _automatic_ column sizes, but it doesn't enforce any minimal width. Your three columns with no other content than the digits 2, 3 and 4 can shrink enough in width, that they still fit into the 1/12 of the container width, that your first column leaves unoccupied. If you _want_ only the `2` column to still appear in the first row, at any screen width - then give it the class `col-1`.

Comment: That means I can insert as many as columns if the columns, with `col` class, having enough widths that fits into the 1/12 the container .

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I got the answer and point from you.